# Deleting JSON object based on attribute

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am working with React, I have got a variable named newtreeData, which looks like:

```
var newTreeData = {
        name: submitted_title,
        resource_link: submitted_resource_link,
        details: submitted_details,
        uuid: submitted_uuid,
        website_image: submitted_website_img,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Edit and save",
            resource_link: "uh",
            uuid: uuid.v4(),
            details: "hi",
            website_image:
              "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/harmonicons-06/64/plus-circle-512.png",
            children: [{...}, {}, ...]
          },




          {
            name: "Edit and save",
            resource_link: "uh",
            uuid: uuid.v4(),
            details: "hi",
            website_image:
              "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/harmonicons-06/64/plus-circle-512.png"
          }
        ]
      };
```

The line `children: [{...}, {}]` is just representing that newTreeData's children can have children which can have children...

Anyways, I wrote a method name **findUUIDthenDelete** which should do in pseudocode: `if(object.uuid == toFindUUID) then delete object`, and here's the full code for findUUIDthenDelete:

```
  findUUIDthenDelete = (orig_data, to_delete_uuid) => {
     var targetIsFound = false;
     if (orig_data.uuid == to_delete_uuid) {
        targetIsFound = true;
     }

     if (targetIsFound == false) {
        if (orig_data.children === undefined) {
     } else {
    //if target not found, run recursion
       orig_data.children.map(eachChildren =>
         this.findUUIDthenDelete(eachChildren, to_delete_uuid)
        );
      }
    } else {
      console.log(orig_data, "this is the child ");
      console.log(orig_data.parent, "is found, deleting its parent");
      delete orig_data

    } 
  };
```

As you can see this method is two parts: first I locate the object which has the uuid that we are trying to seek (potentially with some recursions), then delete the object. However, right now I am getting the "delete in local variable strict mode blah blah" error because of doing `delete orig_data`. Any insights to any workarounds to that error or some totally new way of tackling this? Also sincere apologies if there is an obvious solution I am out of mental energy and unable to think of anything algorithmic at the moment.

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is always a string.

Comment: ... and you `delete` from an object using [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: Not sure if I am missing out on something. I used delete in the second code snippet, it doesn't work due to delete in strict mode error and it appears that I have to do delete object[property name]. But the thing I want to delete is orig_data itself. Maybe I will find a way to map children to parents and then do delete orig_data.parent.child and see if that will work, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function findUUIDthenDelete(tree, uuid) {
  if (!tree.children) return;
  tree.children = tree.children.filter(c => c.uuid !== uuid);
  tree.children.forEach(c => findUUIDthenDelete(c, uuid));
}
```

Should be pretty self-explanatory.
First, if the current node has no children, exit right away.
Next, potentially remove a child from the children array if the `uuid` matches using `filter()`.
Finally, recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'll admit this turned out to be more complicated than I thought, but the solution below will work if you can use Immutable. Essentially it walks your objects and collects the path to find the object that has the uuid and then once it has done that, it removes it.

```js
const testMap = Immutable.fromJS({
  uuid: 1,
  children: [{
    uuid: 2,
    children: [{
        uuid: 3,
        children:[{
          uuid: 8
          }]
      },
      {
        uuid: 4
      },
      {
        uuid: 5
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    uuid: 7
  }]
});

function findPath(checkMap, uuid, pathMap, currentIndex) {
  if (checkMap.has('uuid') && checkMap.get('uuid') === uuid) {
    const updatePathMap = pathMap.get('path').push(currentIndex);
    return new Immutable.Map({
      found: true,
      path: pathMap.get('path').push(currentIndex)
    });
  } else {
    if (checkMap.has('children') && checkMap.get('children').size > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < checkMap.get('children').size; i++) {
        const child = checkMap.get('children').get(i);
        const checkChildPath = findPath(child, uuid, pathMap, i);
        if (checkChildPath.get('found') === true) {
          let updatePath =  checkChildPath.get('path').push('children');
          updatePath = updatePath.push(currentIndex);
          return new Immutable.Map({
            found: true,
            path: updatePath
          });
        }
      }
    }
    return pathMap;
  }
}

const testPath = findPath(testMap, 7, new Immutable.Map({
  found: false,
  path: new Immutable.List()
}), 0);

console.info(testPath);

const testPath2 = findPath(testMap, 8, new Immutable.Map({
  found: false,
  path: new Immutable.List()
}), 0);

console.info(testPath2);

if (testPath2.get('found') === true) {

  const path = testPath2.get('path');
  if (path.size === 1 && path.get(0) === 0) {
    // Your highlest level map has the uuid
  } else {
    const truePath = path.shift();
    const cleanedUpMap = testMap.removeIn(truePath);
    console.info(cleanedUpMap);
  }
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```